# How to export the Energy Usage result datas

Tags: instruments, energy

I used Instruments to import the Energy Diagnostics file from Device.

But how can I export the Energy Consumption result data? such as a csv file? Is it possible?

Comment: Apple says in the Docs that we can export Instruments data as CSV. But it doesn't work for Energy Usage :/ https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/SavingandImportingTraceData/SavingandImportingTraceData.html